# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in

Tags: php, function

i had this proplem and this this my code what can i do to solve this problem ??
i am waiting for help please
i putted asign where is the error but i dont know how to solve it

```html
$amsg = strrip_tags($_post['adminmsg']);
if(isset($_post['do']) and $_post['do'] == 'save'){
    $save = mysql_query("update main_settings set adminmsg='$amsg'")
    or // the error is here but i dont know what is the erroe
    if(isset($save)){
    die ("
    <center>تم حفظ الملاحظة</center>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2; url;=index.php'/>
    ");

    }   
}

# الصفحة المطلوبة
    $page= $_GET['cpages'];
    if (isset ($page)) {
    $url= $page.".php";
        if(file_exists ($url)){
        include $url ;



        }else {
        echo"الصفحة المطلوبة غير متوفرة



        ";
        }


    }else {
    echo"مرحبا بك في لوحة التحكم
    <table align='center' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
            <td class='tbl'>ملاحظات المدير العام</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' class='tbl3'><textarea name='adminmsg' rows='6' cols='80'></textarea></td>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align='center' class='tbl2'><input type='submit' value='حفظ الملاحظة'/>
        </tr>
        </table>


    ";
    }

?>
```

Comment: You can't run PHP in the snippet...

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon on the line before.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_...` functions, they are deprecated. Also, your query is open to SQL injection.

Comment: C'mon, please use some tools for your work! You have a major syntax error, something that is IMPOSSIBLE to create unless you are working with a text editor or something like this. Get professional!

Comment: You have many errors `strrip_tags($_post` <= 2x in that one, *just for starters*.

Comment: some tools like what ??  Hidde

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
$save = mysql_query("update main_settings set adminmsg='$amsg'")
or // the error is here but i dont know what is the erroe
if(isset($save)) {
```

I suspect you're trying to check whether the query ran successfully, so one way would be:

```
$save = mysql_query("update main_settings set adminmsg='$amsg'");
if($save) {
```

P.S. Please migrate from `mysql_` family of function - start using `mysqli` or, better yet, PDO.

Comment: [`Not to mention this...`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703810/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-if-in#comment42000990_26703810) - I chose to stay far away from this one.

Comment: @OsamaBakri Sorry, I missed the semicolon - added it now.